# Print #field_suffix with drupal_render($form['field_custom_text_field'])

Tags: entities, theming

I have a custom module that defines a field_suffix for a custom text field

```
function custom_check_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form){ 
$form['field_url']['und'][0]['#field_suffix']='text goes here';
}
```

I then am calling the field in a user-register.tpl.php as

```
print drupal_render($form['field_reg_site_url']);
```

However, the #field_suffix isn't printing (checked that the value is in the array - yes). It does work (same code pattern) for username. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$form['field_url']['#field_suffix']='text goes here';
```

Also, in your example, the suffix is being set on `field_url` but you are printing `field_reg_site_url`. That could be causing some confusion.